How do I make a streambuilder that returns a DropdownMenuEntry in flutter
This is my relevant code. I am making a dropdownmenu that takes in dropdownMenuEntries, a streamBuilder returns the dropdownmenuentry but I am getting a tupe error.

The element type 'StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot<Object?>>' can't be assigned to the list type 'DropdownMenuEntry'.

DropdownMenu(dropdownMenuEntries:  <DropdownMenuEntry<String>>[
    StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
    stream: _stream,
    builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
      final accounts = snapshot.data.docs;
      final accountName = accounts.data['account name'];

      return DropdownMenuEntry<string>(value: accountName, label: accountName)<string>(value:  snapshot.data.documents.reversed; label: 'Abdi')
    };
  ],
  onSelected: (String? value) {
    accountCurrency = value.toString();
  }),

I am expecting to get the list of account names and balances from firestore and use it to populate the dropdownmenu. I wanted it updated each time a transaction takes place.

You're now trying to stuff the entire list of documents into a single DropdownMenuEntry, which of course doesn't work. You'll need to return a DropdownMenu object instead, and in there for each document from Firestore create a DropdownMenuEntry based on the field value(s) that you want to display.
